# Floodfill/Paint Function, in MASM assembly x86 (DOS)

Tags: assembly, x86, flood-fill

I'm drawing polygons, so how I do? i've a line procedure, so with 4 programmed points, i do that, it works well, and when i use a polygon procedure, it draws and too calculated the center of polygon and save it in a variable, so i want to call a paint procedure (like a floodfill to paint the polygons) using by reference this center point.

It works, buut get a lot of stack... so when I want to draw 22 polygons it halts. Stop everything.

i'm using this following procedure to paint:

```
paint PROC USES SI DI, posi:WORD, k:BYTE      ; posi = y*320+x  K = color
mov di,posi
        mov al,es:[di]
        .if al!=k
                mov al,k
                mov es:[di],al
                mov bx,posi
                inc bx
                mov al,es:[bx]
                .if al!=k
                invoke paint,bx,k
                .endif
                mov bx,posi
                dec bx
                mov al,es:[bx]
                .if al!=k
                invoke paint,bx,k
                .endif
                mov bx,posi
                add bx,320
                mov al,es:[bx]
                .if al!=k
                invoke paint,bx,k
                .endif
                mov bx,posi
                sub bx,320
                mov al,es:[bx]
                .if al!=k
                invoke paint,bx,k
                .endif
      .endif
ret
paint ENDP
```

This function call itself a lot of times to paint.
I wanna to fix the stack problem or make any procedure to draw polygon already filled (a dream...)
I don't now hot to calculate a good return for paint function and run it for 22 polygons.
at start i've in my code

```
.model small,pascal,nearstack
.stack 02000h
.486
```

Comment: Related: https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2998/what-implementations-of-basic-had-a-robust-flood-fill-operator

Comment: It should not matter how many polygons you have. Do you mean 22 sided polygon maybe? Anyway you can at least optimize the recursion e.g. by drawing horizontal lines in a loop and not recursively (works best for convex shapes).

Comment: i'm reading about not recursive methods... i will try write some code using this idea.. but what i really want is a filled polygon algorithm

Comment: It's weird that you keep reloading `posi` and `k` from the stack, when you've told MASM to save/restore SI and DI around this function.  But you're not using SI to hold anything, and not reusing the DI = `posi`, or using addressing modes like `[si-1]` or `[si+320]` outside the if, then maybe an LEA inside the if to generate the register arg.  (If you don't want to write actual asm, you could get a C compiler to generate code for you instead of using MASM directives like `.if al!=k` that hide inefficiency.)  With `k` in a reg, you could be doing `cmp es:[di-320], bl` or something.

Comment: @PeterCordes it's really, thanks... i will rewrite ... at first time i'm using DI directly without posi... i will change these parts... thnaks a lot

Comment: @PeterCordes Do you think that's better I make a procedure without arguments (posi, k) and just use DI and BL instead?

Comment: Register args are generally more efficient, so yes, sure.  I guess that means you wouldn't declare them the same way in MASM, but they're still args!  Normal calling conventions have arg-passing registers call-clobbered, so you might pass the pointer in DX and `mov` it to DI after saving the incoming DI or something.  Of course that would still be recursive, but register args and just saving 2 regs + return address would be less stack space than 2 stack args + 2 saved regs + return address.